How can I replicate only the schema of the tables through SQL server replication?
I’m working to configure the replication of schema changes using replication in sql server, I started researching and some web pages suggest using transactional replica and then disable the option Copy Data.
However in the version I’m working on do not see that option, can you advise me if it is possible to create a publication where only replicate the scheme and how you can work it, please?

The option you need to set is the propagation method for your article(s).
You can set the option to NONE to not propagate any data to subscribers. In the GUI, this is under the Article Properties, under the Statement Delivery section. You set the option for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements to Do not replicate and this should prevent any replication of data for that article.
You can also set it via T-SQL by setting the @ins_cmd, @upd_cmd and @del_cmd parameters to 'NONE' when calling sp_addarticle.
More Info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/set-the-propagation-method-for-data-changes-to-transactional-articles?view=sql-server-ver16
